# matplotlib not plotting scatter data in boxplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to follow the titanic example shown [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/fonnesbeck/5850463). Here is my code so far

```py
    cat_df = DataFrame({"Data": data, "DOW": days_of_week})
    axes = cat_df.boxplot(column="Data", by="DOW")
    axes.set_title("DOW vs Data")
    axes.set_xlabel("DOW")
    axes.set_ylabel("Data")
    for day in ["Fri", "Mon", "Thu", "Tue", "Wed"]:
        y = cat_df.loc[cat_df["DOW"] == day, "Data"]
        x = np.repeat(day, len(y))
        axes.scatter(x, y, color='r', alpha=0.3)
    plt.suptitle('')
    plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image
[image]
as you can see the problem is that the last box does not contain the scatter points of the data. I tried changing the order in which the plots (i.e. drawing the scatter data first and then the boxplots) are drawn, but this does not seemed to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the categorical axes created by `pandas` and by `matplotlib` are incompatible. Pandas order the categories on indices `1,2,...` while matplotlib uses `0,1,...`. The best solution is to only use one tool to do the plotting (either all pandas or all matplotlib), but if you have to mix both, then you have to adjust the x-axis coordinates accordingly:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

axes = tips.boxplot(column="tip", by="day")
axes.set_title("DOW vs Data")
axes.set_xlabel("DOW")
axes.set_ylabel("Data")

for i,day in enumerate(["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]):
    y = tips.loc[tips["day"] == day, "tip"]
    x = np.repeat(i+1, len(y))  # adjust the x data so that Thur will correspond to coordinate 1, Fri to 2, etc
    axes.scatter(x, y, color='r', alpha=0.3)
```

[image]